# Android webview onBackPressed not fired when WebView is focused

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an activity, with a webView(Chromium webView https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview/) inside it.

The screen has two parts, top part is a ViewPager and bottom is a WebView. When the activity is loaded and webView is not in focus, back key works as expected and onBackPressed and onKeyDown are fired.

However, the moment webView receives focus(by tapping or focusing a textfield), the activity doesn't seem to treat back key as expected and both onBackPress and onKeyDown are not fired.

Things I have tried:
- I have tried both onBackPress and onKeyDown.
- Tried setting android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" for the linearlayout, but webView doesn't receive focus anymore.

I believe most of the code is standard java and since the events fire when webView is not in focus, I assume there is something I am not handling well when it comes to focusing a webView.

The activity is a "Fragment Activity"

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.?
Following is the code for backpress and keydown, and even the debug messages are not to be seen and no errors as well.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/order_mode"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        >           
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame_surface_view"
            >
        <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
            android:id="@+id/surface_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_gravity="top" 
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frame_surface_view"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frame_surface_view"  
            android:layout_margin="20dp"      
            >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnGift"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gift" 
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPraise"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/praise" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

            />      
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerPriaseMessages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCount"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_input"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:entries="@array/praise_count_array"
            android:prompt="@string/selectPraise"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />                 
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewRelative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.mogoweb.chrome.WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true" />    
    </RelativeLayout> 
    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The events

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    System.out.println("Back Pressed");
    if(webView.isFocused()){
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();   
    }
    System.out.println("BackPressed");
    if(!giftShown){
        mVideoView.stopPlayback();

        finish();                   
    }else{
        System.out.println("Hiding Fragment Gift");
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        giftShown=false;
    }           

}    
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    System.out.println("onKeyDown");
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) ) {

        if(webView.isFocused()){
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
        System.out.println("BackPressed");
        if(!giftShown){
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            finish();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Hiding Fragment Gift");
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            giftShown=false;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Does it show any error? Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way to solved this problem, add this code on your onCreateView fragment :

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.clearFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

OR try this way on your fragmentActivity :

```
 if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
```

Comment: According to official tutorial(http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/webapps/webview.html), override onKeyDown and handle KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK should work.